# Sort an array of objects in React and render them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects containing some information. I am not able to render them in the order I want and I need some help with that. I render them like this:

```
this.state.data.map(
    (item, i) => <div key={i}> {item.matchID} {item.timeM} {item.description}</div>
)
```

Is it possible to sort them ascending with `item.timeM` in that `map()`-function or do I have to sort them before i use map?

Comment: You have to sort them BEFORE using `map` method.

Comment: @Oen44 is right. But know that the logic and functions (map & sort) aren't React-specific, they're normal JS constructs!

Comment: if you are grabbing `data` from `backend` it would be nice that this `data` already be `sorted`

Answer (score 164, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
// ... rest of code

// copy your state.data to a new array and sort it by itemM in ascending order
// and then map 
const myData = [].concat(this.state.data)
    .sort((a, b) => a.itemM > b.itemM ? 1 : -1)
    .map((item, i) => 
        <div key={i}> {item.matchID} {item.timeM}{item.description}</div>
    );

// render your data here...
```

The method `sort` [will mutate the original array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control) . Hence I create a new array using the `concat` method. The sorting on the field `itemM` should work on sortable entities like string and numbers.

Comment: I think `.sort((a, b) => a.itemM > b.itemM)` is incorrect here (this really threw me off...). It should be `.sort((a, b) => a.itemM - b.itemM)` if `itemM` are numbers, right?

Comment: If `itemM` not numbers it needs to be something more like this:
`.sort((a, b) => a.item.timeM > b.item.timeM ? 1:-1)`

Comment: great answer. It's also well worth being aware of `.localeCompare()`, for example `b.item.timeM.localeCompare(b.item.timeM)`

Comment: it's better to use `lodash` for this kind of operation

Answer (score 24):

You will need to sort your object before mapping over them. And it can be done easily with a `sort()` function with a custom comparator definition like

```
var obj = [...this.state.data];
obj.sort((a,b) => a.timeM - b.timeM);
obj.map((item, i) => (<div key={i}> {item.matchID}  
                      {item.timeM} {item.description}</div>))
```

Answer (score 19):

```js
const list = [
  { qty: 10, size: 'XXL' },
  { qty: 2, size: 'XL' },
  { qty: 8, size: 'M' }
]

list.sort((a, b) => (a.qty > b.qty) ? 1 : -1)

console.log(list)
```

Out Put :

```
[
  {
    "qty": 2,
    "size": "XL"
  },
  {
    "qty": 8,
    "size": "M"
  },
  {
    "qty": 10,
    "size": "XXL"
  }
]
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with React as asked in the question.

Answer (score 9):

```
this.state.data.sort((a, b) => a.item.timeM > b.item.timeM).map(
    (item, i) => <div key={i}> {item.matchID} {item.timeM} {item.description}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try lodash sortBy

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
_.sortBy(data.applications,"id").map(application => (
    console.log("application")
    )
)
```

Read more : [lodash.sortBy](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/lodash/sortby)

Answer (score 7):

```
this.state.data.sort((a, b) => a.objKey > b.objKey ? 1:-1).map((objKey, index))
```

Answer (score 4):

Chrome browser considers integer value as return type not boolean value
so,

```
this.state.data.sort((a, b) => a.item.timeM > b.item.timeM ? 1:-1).map(
    (item, i) => <div key={i}> {item.matchID} {item.timeM} {item.description}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **localeCompare** for strings.
For many alphabets, it's better to use the **string.localeCompare** method to properly sort letters like Ö.

For example, let's sort several countries in German:

```
let countries = ['Österreich', 'Andorra', 'Vietnam']
alert( countries.sort( (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1) )
```

In this case result of sorted array will be next:
Andorra, Vietnam, Österreich (wrong)

```
alert( countries.sort( (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b) ) )
```

On the other hand: Andorra, Österreich, Vietnam (properly)

Comment: This is an underrated answer and the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I found a really good post: [React: how to dynamically sort an array of objects](https://dev.to/ramonak/react-how-to-dynamically-sort-an-array-of-objects-using-the-dropdown-with-react-hooks-195p)

It´s for dropdown, but you can adapt it. The important thing is the way of sorting the array because, as it is explained in the post, react is not realizing about list changes, as the elements are the same.

```
const [currentList, setCurrentList] = useState(new Array());

const sorted = [...dataList].sort((a, b) => b["lotNumber"] - a["lotNumber"]).reverse();

setCurrentList(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toSorted()** instead of sort().
It will create a new array. Sort will mutate your state which isn't something you really want...
so your code will look like this:

```
const sortedArr = this.state
   .toSorted((a, b) => a.itemM > b.itemM ? 1 : -1)
   .map((item, i) => 
       <div key={i}> {item.matchID} {item.timeM}{item.description}</div>
   );
```

Answer (score -3):

This approach worked for me

```
const list = [
  { price: 10, plan: 'a' },
  { price: 2, plan: 'b' },
  { price: 8, plan: 'c' }
];
this.setState({ planList: list.sort((a,b)=> a.price-b.price)  });


render(){
   return(){
      <div>
          this.state.planList !== undefined && this.state.planList !== null && 
          this.state.planList !== '' && this.state.planList.map((ele, index) => {
              return (
                 <div key={index}> {ele.price}{ele.plan}</div>
              )
          })
      </div>
  }
}
```

Thank You