# How to sort a component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an element of the sidebar, on the page of my application I want to sort them by the number of likes. How can I implement sorting at the stage of the map operation, so that the components are drawn correctly?

```js
 return (
        <section>
            <Popular/>
            <div>
                {this.props.object.map((summary, i) =>
                    <SideBarPost id={summary.id}
                                 firstName={summary.User.firstName}
                                 lastName={summary.User.lastName}
                                 title={summary.title}
                                 createdAt={summary.createdAt}
                                 likes={summary.likes.length}
                                 key={i}
                    />)
                }
            </div>
         </section>
```

Comment: For `sort` the array on the `like` key then use the `map` to generate the component.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: You can use something like this `this.props.object.sort((a,b) => b.likes.length - a.likes.length).map(/*component logic here*/);`

Comment: You can use regular [sort array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572436/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-react-and-render-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hassan Imam's  solution in the comments helped:

> You can use something like this `this.props.object.sort((a,b) => b.likes.length - a.likes.length).map(/*component logic here*/);`

Answer (score 0):

const filter1 = [...users].sort((a,b)=> a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
setUsers(filter1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can you please explain your code ?