# Why this sort function is not returning to the original order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a sort function. `productList || filteredInfos`  is the array of data passed down from parent component

```
const sortItems = (data) => {
    let priceArray = [];
    if (filteredState === true) {
      priceArray = filteredInfos;
    } else {
      priceArray = productList;
    }

    if (data === 'Price low - high') {
      priceArray.sort(
        (a, b) => a.discountedPriceWithDouble - b.discountedPriceWithDouble,
      );
    } else if (data === 'Price high - low') {
      priceArray.sort(
        (a, b) => b.discountedPriceWithDouble - a.discountedPriceWithDouble,
      );
    } else {
      priceArray = productList;
    }
    setFilteredInfos(priceArray);
  };
```

What I don't understand is in the `if` condition. sorting price `low-high` & `high-low` is working but in the **`else`** statement, I believe I change this data back to original order.
But the else statement is not working. The data is always sorted in either price `high-low` or `low-high`

Here how I render the data

```
<FlatList
    //bikelist is the data from productList || filteredInfos
    data={bikeList}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
    style={styles.arrayListMargin}
/>
```

Comment: Can't check the very similar closed question from a few minutes ago (deleted now) for differences, is there a difference here?

Comment: Can someone explain why this question getting - . The old question is already deleted because some one suggested an answer which doesn't solve the question itself

Comment: `priceArray = productList` does not make a copy of `productList`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Can you as least leave a comment before closing the question. Your suggested old question doesn't solve my question at all. In the old case

Comment: I didn't close your old question, i didn't read it fully either, because it was already closed. However, if i realize, that i am seeing reposts of closed questions within five minutes, and the old one is deleted, so i can't check, whether i am just getting spammed, i assume that i am.

Comment: Yeah stackoverflow suggest me to delete old question and repost if the previous suggested answer doesn't solve my question. So I am posting a new one. Now I am also getting a minus. So I am kind of confused right now. Actually @Pointy make a nice suggestion

Comment: Someone suggest me to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572436/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-react-and-render-them` go to this link. Which clearly doesn't solve my question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a copy of the array by spreading the items.

```
const sortItems = (data) => {
    const
        directions = {
            'Price low - high': 1,
            'Price high - low': -1
        },
        order = directions[data];
        priceArray = filteredState && order
            ? [...filteredInfos]
            : [...productList],

    if (order) {
        priceArray.sort((a, b) => order * (a.discountedPriceWithDouble - b.discountedPriceWithDouble));
    }

    setFilteredInfos(priceArray);
};
```