# sorting function not working in react table

Tags: reactjs, tsx

So am trying to add sorting my react table component, i have wrote two functions one for sorting in ascending or and the other one for sorting in descending order and want it to fire on onClick but it just doesn't seems to work, i don't know what am doing wrong in the code.
Here is my code:

```
import type { HTMLAttributes, FC } from 'react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Table.css';

export interface Props extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLHRElement> {
    colNames?: [];
    /** Data in JSON to feed the table */
    data?: JSON[];
}
/**
 * Component that serves as an table for ease of templating
 *
 * @return Table component
 */
export const Table: FC<Props> = ({ 
 data = [
    { id: 12, name: 'zebra', Age: 30 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Name2', Age: 30 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Name3', Age: 30 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Name4', Age: 30 },
],
colNames = ['id', 'name', 'Age'], }) => {
    const [sorted, setsorted] = useState(data);

    /** Function to sort ascending order */
    const ascOrder = (): void => {
        setsorted(sorted.sort((a: any, b: any) => a.id - b.id));
    };

    /** Function to sort descending order */
    const descOrder = (): void => {
        setsorted(sorted.sort((a: any, b: any) => b.id - a.id));
    };
    return (
        <div className="my-component-library-table-component-container">
            {data.length > 0 && (
                <table className="my-component-library-table-component" cellSpacing="0">
                    <thead className="header">
                        <tr>
                            {(colNames as any[]).map((headerItem, index) => (
                                <th key={index}>
                                    <span>{headerItem.toUpperCase()}</span>
                                    <button title={headerItem + 'ASC'} onClick={() => ascOrder}>
                                        ↑
                                    </button>
                                    <button title={headerItem + 'DESC'} onClick={() => descOrder}>
                                        ↓
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {Object.values(data).map((obj, index) => (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                {Object.values(obj).map((value, index2) => (
                                    <td key={index2}> {value} </td>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot className="my-component-library-table-component-footer"></tfoot>
                </table>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Willow's Solution:

```
import type { HTMLAttributes, FC } from 'react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Table.css';

export interface Props extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLHRElement> {
    colNames?: [];
    /** Data in JSON to feed the table */
    data?: JSON[];
}
/**
 * Component that serves as an table for ease of templating
 *
 * @return Table component
 */
export const Table: FC<Props> = ({
    data = [
        { id: 12, name: 'zebra', Age: 30 },
        { id: 2, name: 'Name2', Age: 30 },
        { id: 3, name: 'Name3', Age: 30 },
        { id: 4, name: 'Name4', Age: 30 },
    ],
    colNames = ['id', 'name', 'Age'],
}) => {
    const [sorted, setsorted] = useState(data);

    /** Function to sort ascending order */
    const ascOrder = (): void => {
        setsorted(sorted.sort((a: any, b: any) => a.id - b.id));
    };

    /** Function to sort descending order */
    const descOrder = (): void => {
        setsorted(sorted.sort((a: any, b: any) => b.id - a.id));
    };
    return (
        <div className="my-component-library-table-component-container">
            {data.length > 0 && (
                <table className="my-component-library-table-component" cellSpacing="0">
                    <thead className="header">
                        <tr>
                            {(colNames as any[]).map((headerItem, index) => (
                                <th key={index}>
                                    <span>{headerItem.toUpperCase()}</span>
                                    <button title={headerItem + 'ASC'} onClick={ascOrder}>
                                        ↑
                                    </button>
                                    <button title={headerItem + 'DESC'} onClick={descOrder}>
                                        ↓
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {sorted.map((obj, index) => (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                {Object.values(obj).map((value, index2) => (
                                    <td key={index2}> {value} </td>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot className="my-component-library-table-component-footer"></tfoot>
                </table>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `data` ? If you could add that to your question it would be helpful :)

Comment: @Willow edited my question with the value of data and colName please have a look

Comment: If you update to the code in my answer, does the sorting by id work (and the other columns doesn't work), or do none of them still work?

Comment: Non of them work... @Willow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort an array of objects in React and render them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572436/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-react-and-render-them)

Comment: @SiddharthSeth my issue is not with the sorting itself, I have tested it and it works the main goal is to sort by clicking on the button that' what not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import type { HTMLAttributes, FC } from 'react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Table.css';

export interface Props extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLHRElement> {
    colNames?: [];
    /** Data in JSON to feed the table */
    data?: JSON[];
}
/**
 * Component that serves as an table for ease of templating
 *
 * @return Table component
 */
export const Table: FC<Props> = ({ 
 data = [
    { id: 12, name: 'zebra', Age: 30 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Name2', Age: 30 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Name3', Age: 30 },
    { id: 4, name: 'Name4', Age: 30 },
],
colNames = ['id', 'name', 'Age'], }) => {
    const [sorted, setSorted] = useState(data);

    /** Function to sort ascending order */
    const ascOrder = (): void => {
        setSorted([].concat(sorted).sort((a: any, b: any) => a.id - b.id));
    };

    /** Function to sort descending order */
    const descOrder = (): void => {
        setSorted([].concat(sorted).sort((a: any, b: any) => b.id - a.id));
    };
    return (
        <div className="my-component-library-table-component-container">
            {data.length > 0 && (
                <table className="my-component-library-table-component" cellSpacing="0">
                    <thead className="header">
                        <tr>
                            {(colNames as any[]).map((headerItem, index) => (
                                <th key={index}>
                                    <span>{headerItem.toUpperCase()}</span>
                                    <button title={headerItem + 'ASC'} onClick={() => ascOrder()}>
                                        ↑
                                    </button>
                                    <button title={headerItem + 'DESC'} onClick={() => descOrder()}>
                                        ↓
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {Object.values(sorted).map((obj, index) => (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                {Object.values(obj).map((value, index2) => (
                                    <td key={index2}> {value} </td>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot className="my-component-library-table-component-footer"></tfoot>
                </table>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Please try the above code snippet instead ... You are actually not calling the sorting functions at all ... I added the parens to invoke them on click event ... That should work ... Let me know otherwise...

Comment: no siddhart nothing

Comment: Updated my answer with fixes suggested at the Url in my comment ...

Comment: Still nothing @Siddharth Seth

Comment: Please try once more and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not actually calling the `ascOrder` and `descOrder` functions. You are defining inline functions that return those functions. Instead, try this:

```
<button title={headerItem + 'ASC'} onClick={ascOrder}>
    ↑
</button>
<button title={headerItem + 'DESC'} onClick={descOrder}>
    ↓
</button>
```

EDIT: in addition, you are also mapping the original `data` instead of the sorted version. Try changing this:

```
{Object.values(data).map((obj, index) => (
```

to this:

```
{Object.values(sorted).map((obj, index) => (
```

EDIT:
Shouldn't use `Object.values` if we want to keep the order!! Not sure how I missed that before.

Try this

```js
{sorted.map(obj => (
```

EDIT: Maybe it's because you're using the indexes as keys. Instead of this:

```
                    <tbody>
                        {sorted.map((obj, index) => (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                {Object.values(obj).map((value, index2) => (
                                    <td key={index2}> {value} </td>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
```

Try this:

```
                    <tbody>
                        {sorted.map((obj) => (
                            <tr key={obj.id}>
                                {Object.values(obj).map((value, index2) => (
                                    <td key={index2}> {value} </td>
                                ))}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: nope does't work tried that first @Willow

Comment: Found another issue. Give that a try?

Comment: this seems to be the perfect answer but still even this doesn't work

Comment: Updated this again. Lmk if that helps

Comment: am sorry to say but still nothing....am updating my question with how my current code looks like after adding your solution have a look

Comment: Another edit: might be an issue with using keys as indexes.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but no it still doesn't work i tried console.log the onclick functiona and everythings seems to work fine on console onclick works and i get the sorted data but it's just not rendering on the page may be dom issue something