# Sort Flatlist based on true false - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to sort flatlist based on favorites. (Favorites at the start and the other after them).

(This is how it looks right now)
[image]
I want the favorited one to be at top (there can be more than 1 favorites, and everyone should be at top)

This is my code:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.app}>
      <TopBar />

        <FlatList 
          data={data}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Job data={item}/>}
        />
</SafeAreaView>
```

Each item in the array are built like this:

```
let object = {
        "mispar_rechev": item.mispar_rechev,
        "tozeret_nm": item.tozeret_nm,
        "shnat_yitzur": item.shnat_yitzur,
        "kinuy_mishari": item.kinuy_mishari,
        "ramat_gimur": item.ramat_gimur,
        "favorite": flag, //(true / false)
};
```

[image]
This is how I want my flatlist to look like.
I haven't found something like this on internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort an array of objects in React and render them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572436/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-react-and-render-them)

Comment: No, It doesn't. For example I have this data: {false,  true, false, false, true}. I'd like to sort it like this {true, true, false, false, false}

Comment: Now I think u should understand my question better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the `data` array, and Flatlist will be render as you wish:

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.favorite === true && b.favorite === false) {
    return -1;
  } else if (a.favorite === false && b.favorite === true) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```